# Configure Bind to use specific server as starting point for recursive query?

Tags: dns, bind

I'm attempting to setup a Bind DNS server which (for security purposes) is highly limiting.

Essentially I only want to allow DNS queries to be made to a particular set of DNS servers which do not enable recursive queries. These servers are authoritative for some of the domains I will be querying, and in other cases will instead refer a different DNS server as authoritative (not in the original set, yet that I trust by extension).

I'm trying to set things up so that when a query is made of my server, it will essentially recursively attempt to satisfy the query but only using my particular set of servers as a starting point. Is such a thing possible with Bind?

I originally tried to set up my DNS server as a forwarder, however in that case it would fail whenever the original set was not authoritative for the given domain (returning just a list of authorities but no answer).

This seems like a simple use case but I can't seem to find a way to accomplish it, am I missing something obvious?